# How do I plot multiple FacetGrids on one window?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, facet-grid

In the code below I can place two simple seaborn plots in one window by passing `ax=ax[i]` argument to each, does not work for `FacetGrid()`. Similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60602704/seaborn-arrange-multiple-facetgrids), wondering if someone has an idea about how to do this. Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')

########################
# Works :)
########################
fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
sns.regplot(x='total_bill', y='tip', data=df, ax=ax[0])         # plot #1
sns.boxplot(x='day', y='total_bill', data=df, ax=ax[1])         # plot #2
plt.show()

########################
# Does not work :(
########################
fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="time", ax=ax[0])                             # FacetGrid #1
g.map(plt.hist, "tip")

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="sex", hue="smoker", col_wrap=2, ax=ax[1])    # FacetGird #2
g.map(plt.scatter, "total_bill", "tip", alpha=.7)
g.axes[-1].legend() 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because FacetGrid in itself produces subplots and creates a single figure. Subplots aren't allowed with FacetGrid. The only solution to this is to merge your FacetGrids together to create one plot -- however this is no easy task unless your axis are the same.

Workarounds are possible as described here:
[combine different seaborn facet grids into single plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44158276/combine-different-seaborn-facet-grids-into-single-plot)

Answer (score 2):

One (admittedly not particularly neat solution), is to define your own `FacetGrid` class (see the code [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/axisgrid.py)), that takes in a `fig` argument, so that you can pass it [subfigures](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subfigures.html). E.g.:

```py
from itertools import product
import warnings

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from seaborn.axisgrid import FacetGrid, Grid
from seaborn._oldcore import categorical_order
from seaborn.utils import _disable_autolayout

class FacetGridWithFigure(FacetGrid):
    def __init__(
        self, data, *,
        row=None, col=None, hue=None, col_wrap=None,
        sharex=True, sharey=True, height=3, aspect=1, palette=None,
        row_order=None, col_order=None, hue_order=None, hue_kws=None,
        dropna=False, legend_out=True, despine=True,
        margin_titles=False, xlim=None, ylim=None, subplot_kws=None,
        gridspec_kws=None, fig=None, # additional fig argument 
    ):

        # make sure to init the parent of FacetGrid
        super(FacetGrid, self).__init__()

        # Determine the hue facet layer information
        hue_var = hue
        if hue is None:
            hue_names = None
        else:
            hue_names = categorical_order(data[hue], hue_order)

        colors = self._get_palette(data, hue, hue_order, palette)

        # Set up the lists of names for the row and column facet variables
        if row is None:
            row_names = []
        else:
            row_names = categorical_order(data[row], row_order)

        if col is None:
            col_names = []
        else:
            col_names = categorical_order(data[col], col_order)

        # Additional dict of kwarg -> list of values for mapping the hue var
        hue_kws = hue_kws if hue_kws is not None else {}

        # Make a boolean mask that is True anywhere there is an NA
        # value in one of the faceting variables, but only if dropna is True
        none_na = np.zeros(len(data), bool)
        if dropna:
            row_na = none_na if row is None else data[row].isnull()
            col_na = none_na if col is None else data[col].isnull()
            hue_na = none_na if hue is None else data[hue].isnull()
            not_na = ~(row_na | col_na | hue_na)
        else:
            not_na = ~none_na

        # Compute the grid shape
        ncol = 1 if col is None else len(col_names)
        nrow = 1 if row is None else len(row_names)
        self._n_facets = ncol * nrow

        self._col_wrap = col_wrap
        if col_wrap is not None:
            if row is not None:
                err = "Cannot use `row` and `col_wrap` together."
                raise ValueError(err)
            ncol = col_wrap
            nrow = int(np.ceil(len(col_names) / col_wrap))
        self._ncol = ncol
        self._nrow = nrow

        # Calculate the base figure size
        # This can get stretched later by a legend
        # TODO this doesn't account for axis labels
        figsize = (ncol * height * aspect, nrow * height)

        # Validate some inputs
        if col_wrap is not None:
            margin_titles = False

        # Build the subplot keyword dictionary
        subplot_kws = {} if subplot_kws is None else subplot_kws.copy()
        gridspec_kws = {} if gridspec_kws is None else gridspec_kws.copy()
        if xlim is not None:
            subplot_kws["xlim"] = xlim
        if ylim is not None:
            subplot_kws["ylim"] = ylim

        # --- Initialize the subplot grid
        # create figure if one not given as argument
        if fig is None:
            with _disable_autolayout():
                fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)

        if col_wrap is None:

            kwargs = dict(squeeze=False,
                          sharex=sharex, sharey=sharey,
                          subplot_kw=subplot_kws,
                          gridspec_kw=gridspec_kws)

            axes = fig.subplots(nrow, ncol, **kwargs)

            if col is None and row is None:
                axes_dict = {}
            elif col is None:
                axes_dict = dict(zip(row_names, axes.flat))
            elif row is None:
                axes_dict = dict(zip(col_names, axes.flat))
            else:
                facet_product = product(row_names, col_names)
                axes_dict = dict(zip(facet_product, axes.flat))

        else:

            # If wrapping the col variable we need to make the grid ourselves
            if gridspec_kws:
                warnings.warn("`gridspec_kws` ignored when using `col_wrap`")

            n_axes = len(col_names)
            axes = np.empty(n_axes, object)
            axes[0] = fig.add_subplot(nrow, ncol, 1, **subplot_kws)
            if sharex:
                subplot_kws["sharex"] = axes[0]
            if sharey:
                subplot_kws["sharey"] = axes[0]
            for i in range(1, n_axes):
                axes[i] = fig.add_subplot(nrow, ncol, i + 1, **subplot_kws)

            axes_dict = dict(zip(col_names, axes))

        # --- Set up the class attributes

        # Attributes that are part of the public API but accessed through
        # a  property so that Sphinx adds them to the auto class doc
        self._figure = fig
        self._axes = axes
        self._axes_dict = axes_dict
        self._legend = None

        # Public attributes that aren't explicitly documented
        # (It's not obvious that having them be public was a good idea)
        self.data = data
        self.row_names = row_names
        self.col_names = col_names
        self.hue_names = hue_names
        self.hue_kws = hue_kws

        # Next the private variables
        self._nrow = nrow
        self._row_var = row
        self._ncol = ncol
        self._col_var = col

        self._margin_titles = margin_titles
        self._margin_titles_texts = []
        self._col_wrap = col_wrap
        self._hue_var = hue_var
        self._colors = colors
        self._legend_out = legend_out
        self._legend_data = {}
        self._x_var = None
        self._y_var = None
        self._sharex = sharex
        self._sharey = sharey
        self._dropna = dropna
        self._not_na = not_na

        # --- Make the axes look good

        self.set_titles()
        self.tight_layout()

        if despine:
            self.despine()

        if sharex in [True, 'col']:
            for ax in self._not_bottom_axes:
                for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
                    label.set_visible(False)
                ax.xaxis.offsetText.set_visible(False)
                ax.xaxis.label.set_visible(False)

        if sharey in [True, 'row']:
            for ax in self._not_left_axes:
                for label in ax.get_yticklabels():
                    label.set_visible(False)
                ax.yaxis.offsetText.set_visible(False)
                ax.yaxis.label.set_visible(False)

    def tight_layout(self):
        # subfigures don't have a tight layout option
        pass
```

You can then do, e.g.:

```py
import seaborn as sns

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))

# create subfigs
subfigs = fig.subfigures(1, 2, wspace=0.07)

g1 = FacetGridWithFigure(tips, col="time",  row="sex", fig=subfigs[0])
g1.map(sns.scatterplot, "total_bill", "tip")

g2 = FacetGridWithFigure(tips, col="size", height=2.5, col_wrap=3, fig=subfigs[1])
g2.map(sns.histplot, "total_bill")

plt.show()
```

which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use [patchworklib](https://github.com/ponnhide/patchworklib), you can do as follow.

```py
import patchworklib as pw
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pw.overwrite_axisgrid()

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
g0 = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="time") #FacetGrid #1
g0.map(plt.hist, "tip")
g0 = pw.load_seaborngrid(g0, label="g0")


g1 = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="sex", hue="smoker", col_wrap=2, height=3, aspect= 1) #FacetGird #2
g1.map(plt.scatter, "total_bill", "tip", alpha=.7)
g1 = pw.load_seaborngrid(g1, label="g0")

(g0|g1).savefig()
```

In result, you can obtain the following figure output.
[image]