# seaborn scatter plots side by side in python in a single cell in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, seaborn, data-visualization

I have a pandas data frame "data" with four columns age, year, nodes, status.
Status being the class/target variable which has only two values 1 - alive and 2- dead.

```
sns.FacetGrid(data, hue="status", size=5).map(sns.distplot, "year").add_legend();
plt.show();
sns.FacetGrid(data, hue="status", size=5).map(sns.distplot, "age").add_legend();
plt.show();
```

After executing the above statements in  single cell in jupyter, the output will be two plots one after another in a single cell.

I would want to print these plots side by side in a single cell. Please help.

Comment: Try [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [combine different seaborn facet grids into single plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44158276/combine-different-seaborn-facet-grids-into-single-plot)

Answer (score -1):

Try running this code!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # You would have already imported this

plt.subplot(221)
sns.FacetGrid(data, hue="status", size=5).map(sns.distplot, "year").add_legend();
# plt.show();
plt.subplot(222)
sns.FacetGrid(data, hue="status", size=5).map(sns.distplot, "age").add_legend();
# plt.show();
```

Ideally, the plots should be displayed now. If they don't, uncomment `plt.show()`

Comment: Thanks neeraj for the answer, unfortunately it is not working